does Hegel's Dialectical Materialism needs justification when we re-examine the notion of "opposite" and whether that's a fact of the world?
Hegel basically says thesis-antithesis-synthesis, and this works because there are opposition of ideas or there are contradictions
Derrida also uses concepts like "binary oppositions"
he considers "writing" and "speech" or "man" or "woman" to be opposites
but is that true?
Is man the opposite of woman?! that doesn't makes much sense, i would say man is different from woman and that's a fact of the world but man is opposite of a woman is not a "fact" of the world

Consider -1 and 1 as well, at first glance it seems they are mortal enemies or opposites but seeing it like below:
...,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,...
you can see it's not opposition it's just a different number

We can say the same thing about law of non contradiction and "true" or "flase" 
don't get me wrong, I'm a fan of this law.
I agree that a proposition is either true or false, two choice, but this can still be interpreted that there are only two "different" options and not opposition in a Hegelian sense

long story short, opposition seems like an a priori knowledge we use to understand the world but it's not something that exist in the world

"Hegel's dialectical materialism"??? Are you confusing him with Marx?  There is no "thesis-antithesis-synthesis" in Hegel either, that is Fichte's triad.

@Conifold dialectical materialism is hegelian, i know it's by marx but marx uses hegel's logic, "thesis-antithesis-synthesis" is invented by Fichte, i agree but hegel uses it in his logic, (being, nothing) and (becoming) is this triad

What Conifold points out here is that it is probably not a good idea to take several authors with superficially similar structures and then assume that one can use the terms of one author to describe the others without problems, or that when one of the authors runs into specific philosophical problems and inconsistencies, so will the others. It is mandatory for good philosophical thought to avoid both of these problematic thought patterns.
